# JSF2 difference between composite and cc

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I was trying to create a composite component based on [BalusC's excellent article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html).
I couldn't get the attributes or any value from the backing component. Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface componentType="test">
    <composite:attribute name="something" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="#{composite.attrs.something}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{composite.hello}" />
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

I found out that the same code works then i use the "cc" namespace instead of "composite". Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<cc:interface componentType="test">
    <cc:attribute name="something" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.something}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.hello}" />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

The question is, why is it not working with the "composite" namespace?
I couldn't find any information that "composite" is a JSF reserved word or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing XML namespace with [implicit EL object](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects). The `cc` in `#{cc}` does not refer to the composite component XML namespace currently being used. It just references the composite component instance in the EL scope and is a fixed name. This construct works as good, with `composite` XML namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface componentType="test">
    <composite:attribute name="something" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.something}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.hello}" />
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

*(note: I'd rather have used `<ui:component>` instead of `<?xml?><!DOCTYPE><html>`, exactly like as in the blog article which you linked there)*

As to XML namespace, `composite` is unnecessarily long and does not fit nicely among all other abbreviated XML namespaces like `h`, `f`, `c`, etc. That's why many developers opt to use `cc` instead of `composite` as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/tld-summary.html) by JSF itself. Please note that the composite tag documentation itself also uses `#{cc}` throughout the examples with `composite` XML namespace.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the explanation. You're our JSF hero ;).

Comment: Thanks for the <ui:component> note also.